# how to use ready-made Func<> delegate in QueryAsync?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, dapper

I have such a problem that I have the same Func in my methods. I took it out separately, but now the problem is how to pass parameters to it. I want to use it in several places, but I don't know how to get the necessary parameters from the QueryAsync method

My func delegate

```
private Func<Authors, AuthorInPrintingEditions, PrintingEditions, Authors> _relationDelegate =
        (Authors authors, AuthorInPrintingEditions relation, PrintingEditions printingEdition) =>
        {
            if (!_dictionaryResult.ContainsKey(authors.Id))
            {
                _dictionaryResult.Add(authors.Id, new Authors()
                {
                    Id = authors.Id,
                    Name = authors.Name,
                    AuthorInPrintingEditions = printingEdition == null
                        ? new List<AuthorInPrintingEditions>()
                        : new List<AuthorInPrintingEditions>()
                        {
                            new AuthorInPrintingEditions()
                            {
                                PrintingEdition = printingEdition
                            }
                        }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                if (printingEdition != null)
                {
                    _dictionaryResult[authors.Id].AuthorInPrintingEditions.Add(new AuthorInPrintingEditions()
                    {
                        PrintingEdition = printingEdition
                    });
                }
            }

            return authors;
        };
```

My method, when I want use it

```
        using (var conneсtion = CreateConnection())
        {
            await conneсtion.QueryAsync<Authors, AuthorInPrintingEditions, PrintingEditions, Authors>(query,
                (authors, authorInPrintingEditions, printingEdition), <--- in this row I want use delegate
                new { skip = skip, pageSize = pageSize }, splitOn: "Id,AuthorId,Id");

            return _dictionaryResult.Values.ToList();
        }
```

I don't understand how to pass parameters to it and whether it is generally possible, or it will still be easier to copy and paste

Comment: In that row just put `_relationDelegate `.

Comment: One option to parametrize your reusable delegate is to expose both the delegate and parameters as an instance members of some class.
Then, when you need this delegate, create instance of that class, set parameters and pass on the delegate to query async.

Comment: it's all wrong ... return `IEnumerable<AuthorPrintingEditionPair>`  then use `ToDictionary(...)` extension

Comment: @Dusan Yes I did it, it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to reuse the delegate and also be able to use parameters,
try using something like this:

```
public class AuthorsMapper
{
    public int Parameter1;
    public string Parameter2;

    public Func<Authors, AuthorInPrintingEditions, PrintingEditions, Authors> Map =>
    // Your existing code that can now use parameters
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var mapper = new AuthorsMapper 
{
    Parameter1 = 742,
    Parameter2 = "House"
};

await conneсtion.QueryAsync<Authors, AuthorInPrintingEditions, PrintingEditions, Authors>
    (query, mapper.Map, ...);
```

Comment: I would call it something other than `Delegate`.

Comment: Thank you, Dapper is calling this function a `Map`, so I will change my answer conform to that one.

Comment: Give it a meaningful name; something like `PrintingEditionsDelegate` or `PrintingEditionsMap` or `AuthorEditionsMap`.

Comment: The `Deleagate` is then also misleading.
Since this is used in context of `Dapper` I would stick to the naming used in there.
From the Dapper source code: `Func<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TReturn> map`

Comment: That's the name of the parameter, not the name of the argument.  Anyway, I've said my peace.